# drawing line by tracking finger in opencv

Tags: opencv, drawing, line, tracking, opencv3.0

I am new to opencv, I want to detect if one finger is up it will draw a line on screen, I read some tutorials, I am tracking the finger Point successfully and it is being updated continuously.I do something like below. when I move the finger it does draw a short red line but it is transient and be disappeared right after. I need the drawing line to stay there but I have no idea how to do it and I can not find solution,I am really Hoping to hear from you, thank you very much.

```
int lastx = -1;
int lasty = -1;

void trackingfinger(....)
{
.........
if(drawing == true)
   draw(BGR_frame,Point finger)
}


void draw(BGR_frame, Point finger)
{
    int x = finger.x;
    int y = finger.y;

    if (lastx > 0 && lasty > 0 && x > 0 && y > 0)
    {
    line(BGR_frame, Point(x, y), Point(lastx, lasty), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
    }

    lastx = x;
    lasty = y;
}

int main (void)
{
 while(true)
{
..... the function is called here.
}
}
```

Comment: push back the new point to some dynamic array (e.g. a std::vector) and then loop over the whole array and draw lines from point to point.

Comment: @Micka it works! thanks for your idea. I forgot to check the array must have at least two elements to run.

Comment: nice to hear. was just typing an answer but was interrupted :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the presented part of code correctly, you cannot do it this way. How do you decide when the drawing should begin and when it should end? The `line` function needs one starting point and one ending point.

Either "draw" pixel by pixel, all the coordinates where the finger is moving, if you want it to follow the finger => in the end, it will not be one line

Or implement some action, that will tell "now the finger points  to starting point" and "now it points to ending point"

Comment: its supposed to start drawing when only one finger is up and stop if there are more than one finger up (I use convexity defect). sorry for not being clear, now I use a dynamic array to hold all the points and loop draw it, you remain me to check it must have more than 2 points to avoid the old error, thanks